# Angular spec component not found

Tags: angular

Angular spec file import the component into two ways, for the first way i'm getting error why? Second way i'm getting result. What is main reason? VS code now import the component path from app it self.

First way

```
import { FormlyTicketPageComponent } from "app/components/mycomponent.component";
```

Second way

```
import { FormlyTicketPageComponent } from "../../components/mycomponent.component";
```

Comment: Is the first link automatically generated by intellisense? Verify that your baseUrl in tsconfig is set to './src'

Comment: What does your folder structure look like in File Explorer or Finder? Maybe that will give you a pointer - first is absolute, second is relative path.

Comment: Which is the good approach? relative or absolute path?